# What's the cleanest way to get record as string in FileHelpers?

Tags: c#, filehelpers

When I'm parsing a text file, and importing it in my application through the (truly wonderful) FileHelpers library, for each error that occurs I want to log in a separate text file the record that failed (along with the error of course), like

```
Error: The record ..... failed with error ....
```

This brings the question in the title: I see there's the method 
`WriteString(IEnumerable<T>)`, but if I call

```
string recordAsString = engine.WriteString(new List<T>() { record });
```

the result string contains a new line in it, and the only way I managed to "clean" it is

```
recordAsString = recordAsString.Substring(0, recordAsString.Length - 2);
```

Is there a cleaner way, ie a method that returns the record as a string that doesn't contain any new line?

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try with

```
var recordAsString = engine.Options.RecordToString(record);
```

Thanks for using the library